# Prove that $ \overline {A^\complement} = (A°)^\complement $

Tags: general-topology

> Prove that $\overline {A^\complement} = (A°)^\complement $

To show that $\overline {A^\complement} \subseteq  (A°)^\complement$

We first show
$A^\complement \subseteq  (A°)^\complement ...(*) $

We know that since $ A°\subseteq A \qquad (*)$ is automatically follows . 
The part I didn't understand is the following:

> Then we conclude that since $ (A°)^\complement$ is closed 
>   $\therefore \overline {A^\complement} \subseteq  (A°)^\complement$

Comment: Do you understand that $(A°)^\complement$ is closed?

Comment: Yes, since A° is open,and thus complement of it is closed

Comment: Well if $B\subseteq F$ where $F$ is closed then $\overline B\subseteq F$. Actually you can define $\overline B$ as the intersection of all closed sets that contain $B$. Do you practicize another definition of $\overline B$?

Comment: Actually I intuitively felt that it is somehow related to the thm which says let $E \subseteq <X,d> \quad$ , then $\overline E \quad$ is the smallest closed set containing $E$  However I cannot use this theorem in the proof

Comment: You don't need theorems here. What is your definition of closure of $B$?

Comment: The closure of $B\quad$ denoted by $\overline B \quad$  is the set  $B\cup B' \quad$  where $B' \quad$  is the set of all accumulation points of $B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be that $B\subseteq F$ where $F$ is a closed set.

Since $B\subseteq F$ every accumulation point of $B$ is automatically an accumulation point of $F$.

Since $F$ is closed it will contain all its accumulation points and we conclude now that it will contain all the accumulation points of $B$.

That means that $\overline B=B\cup B'\subseteq F$.

You can apply this in your special case where $F=(A°)^\complement$ is a closed set that contains $B=A^{\complement}$ as a subset.

---

Btw, I dislike your definition of $\overline B$. In my view it is better to define $\overline B$ as intersection of all closed sets that contain $B$ as a subset. Then it is immediate that $\overline B$ is closed itself and can be described as the "smallest closed set" that contains $B$ as subset.

This must be accompanied with the theorem (not definition) that $\overline B=B\cup B'$.

Answer (score 0):

$\overline{A^c}=\bigcap\{F_i\subset X\,|\, \text{$F_i$ is closed, $A^c\subset F_i$}\}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(closure definition)}$

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=\bigcap\{F_i=U_i^c\subset X\,|\, \text{$U_i$ is open, $A^c\subset U_i^c$}\}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(closed set definition)}$

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=\bigcap\{U_i^c\subset X\,|\, \text{$U_i$ is open, $U_i\subset A$}\}$

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=(\bigcup\{U_i\subset X\,|\, \text{$U_i$ is open, $U_i\subset A$}\})^c\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(Morgan)}$

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=(A^\circ)^c\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(interior definition)}$